# Getting hierchical data from redis with node.js

Tags: node.js, recursion, redis

I was hoping that someone out there could come to my rescue with this.  For some reason, I can't get my mind around recursion in node.js.  It doesn't even have to be recursion, if there's another way.

I'm using redis sets to store a hierarchy in sets:

```
SADD parents.<name> <parent1> <parent2>
```

then, parent1 and parent2 will also have entries, and on up.  I want to convert it to a JSON array of objects.

The JSON will look like this:

```
[
 {
     label: <name>,
     parents: [
         { label: <parent1>,
           parents: [ {label: <grandparent1>}] },
         { label: <parent2> }
     ]
 }
]
```

And so on and so forth.  This should be able to work for any depth, although on average it will only be 4-6 nodes deep.

Here's some code I've been playing with that just gets me the first level:

```
var redis = require('node-redis');
var r_client = redis.createClient();

function get_parents (name, current, cb) {

        var output = new Array;
        output.push( { label: name, parents: [] } );

        r_client.smembers('parents.' + name, function(err, reply) {
            for (var i = 0; i < reply.length; i++)
            {
                var name = reply[i].toString('utf8');
                output[i].parents.push({label: name, parents: [] });
             }
             cb (output);
        });
}

get_parents( 'bob', function(out) {console.log('Final output: ' + JSON.stringify( out ))} );
```

I'm basically wanting to do this:

- Start at root node. Call redis, get parents.
- Build object for root
  node.
- Call same function to build the other objects.
- As calls to redis begin to come back null, the calls will return and start to combine objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Updated get_parents (still doesn't work):

```
function get_parents (name, cb) {
    r_client.smembers('parents.' + name, function(err, reply) {
    for (var i = 0; i < reply.length; i++)
    {
      var name = reply[i].toString('utf8');
      output.push( { label: name, parents: [] } );
      output[i].parents = get_parents (output[i].parents.name, cb);
    }

    cb (output);
  });
}
```

EDIT:  I decided to use Promises, so [I pursued that option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904745/understanding-promises-in-node-js-for-recursive-function).  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: a short way would be to store a json to each `parent.name` instead of a set

Comment: @GeoPhoenix - I agree, but this is part of a larger project, so it makes sense to do it this way.

Comment: well just keep in mind that redis is not meant to be a database, such as mongoDB or mysql which have build functionality for doing this, or storing in a way that's "making sense", redis, is just a key value store, so IMHO storing something that you have fetched from another source, to Redis, in lets say `tree.NAME` with expiration.. would make better sense than querying for hierarchical data, i mean, twitter followers/following its ok, but storing something like a tree in such way , kind of misses the point of redis. not saying that's not feasible ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: I made a NodeJS module ([**RedisTree**](https://github.com/FGRibreau/redistree)) and a [**blog post**](http://blog.fgribreau.com/2013/09/how-to-load-save-trees-using-redis-sets.html) explaining the implementation.

---

**The above code is the initial implementation**

Nice challenge! Here is an implementation that matches your requirement, I added a ".save(tree, f)" method, it uses [**lodash**](http://lodash.com), [**async**](https://github.com/caolan/async) and of course [**node_redis**](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis).

```js
var sampleTree = [{
  label: 'label1',
  parents: [{
    label: 'label2',
    parents: [{
      label: 'label4',
      parents: []
    }]
  }, {
    label: 'label3',
    parents: []
  }]
}];

// Note: it's required to use a set in order to retrieve data
// SET:
// sadd label1 label2 label3
// sadd label2 label4
var _     = require('lodash');
var async = require('async');
var redis = require('redis').createClient();


function RedisTree(){}

/**
 * Iteratively & asynchronously retrieve an item from Redis
 * @param  {String} label label name (set name)
 * @param  {Function} f(err, arrayOfItems)
 */
RedisTree.prototype._getItem = function(label, f) {
  var parent = _.isArray(_.last(arguments)) ? _.last(arguments) : [];

  this.members(label, function(err, cards){
    var item = {
      label: this.label(label),
      parents: []
    };
    parent.push(item);

    if(cards.length === 0){return f(null, parent);}

    async.map(cards, _.partialRight(this._getItem.bind(this), item.parents), function(e){f(e, parent);});
  }.bind(this));
};

RedisTree.prototype._saveItem = function(item, f) {
  var labels = _.pluck(item.parents, 'label');
  if(labels.length === 0){return f();}

  redis.sadd(item.label, labels, function(err){
    if(err){return f(err);}
    this._saveItems(item.parents, f);
  }.bind(this));
};

/**
 *
 * @param  {Array} arrToSave array of items
 * @param  {Function} f(err)
 */
RedisTree.prototype._saveItems = function(arrToSave, f) {
  async.forEach(arrToSave, this._saveItem.bind(this), f);
};

/**
 * Retrieve a name from the label
 * Can be overridden to provide namespace support
 * e.g. return label.substring(2);
 * @return {[type]} [description]
 */
RedisTree.prototype.label = function(label){return label;};

/**
 * Retrieve every members of the `label` set from redis
 * Can be overridden to provide namespace support
 * e.g. redis.smembers('ns.'+label, f);
 * @param {[type]} label [description]
 * @param {[type]} f     [description]
 */
RedisTree.prototype.members = function(label, f) {redis.smembers(label, f);};

/**
 * Load a tree from Redis
 * @param  {String} startLabel Were to start
 * @param  {Function} f(err, tree)
 */
RedisTree.prototype.load = function(startLabel, f){this._getItem(startLabel, f);};

/**
 * Save a tree from Redis
 * @param  {Array} treeArray
 * @param  {Function} f(err, tree)
 */
RedisTree.prototype.save = function(treeArray, f){this._saveItems(treeArray, f);};
```

Here is how to use it:

```
var t = new RedisTree();

// Save the sampleTree
t.save(sampleTree, function(err){
  // or ... retrieve it starting at "label1"
  t.load('label1', function(err, tree){
    console.log("sampleTree === ", JSON.stringify(tree, null, 1));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Going over this in my head.

Comment: Do you need anything else or is my answer enough?

Comment: I think your answer is enough, but I'm not good enough at Node and JS to fully understand everything.  I posted a link on reddit, and someone replied with a solution using promises.  I think it makes more sense to me.  I'll play with both tonight.  And thank you for taking up the challenge!!

Comment: @coding_hero I'd love to see the link to the Reddit post. FGRibreau, very nice!

Comment: @BrandonTilley - [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904745/understanding-promises-in-node-js-for-recursive-function) is what I ended up with.  FGRibreau's answer was great, but the promises approach just made more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can't just store it as JSON on disk or with MongoDB?  Also why does your desired result list parents instead of children?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the process is already implemented in Redis.

That's the way the result needs to be, starting with the root (requested), and all parents and grand-parents following.  This isn't for a family tree, this is for another type of hierarchical data.