# Understanding promises in node.js for recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise

I'm trying to use recursive calls to get data out of redis, stopping and returning when the members return null.

So my data is added like this:

```
SADD parents.<name> <parent1> <parent2>
SADD parents.<parent1> <grandparent1> <grandparent2>
...
```

And the final data should look like:

```
[
 {
     label: <name>,
     parents: [
         { label: <parent1>,
           parents: [ {label: <grandparent1>}, {label: <grandparent2> }] },
         { label: <parent2> }
     ]
 }
]
```

Here's the code I'm messing with (sort of cobbled together from different sources), but I have no idea what I'm doing.  Not sure if this code is even useful, I could be way off track.

```
var redis = require('node-redis');
var r_client = redis.createClient();
var Q = require('q');


function getFromRedis(nodeName){
        var ret = Q.defer();
        r_client.smembers('parents.' + nodeName,function(err,val){
                if (err) ret.reject(err);
                else {
                        var constructedObject={};  //this is our returned object
                        var dependents=[];
                        if (val)
                        {
                                for (var k in val){  //iterate the keys in val
                                        constructedObject.name = val[k];

                                        dependents.push(getFromRedis(val[k])
                                        .then(function(subVal){
                                                constructedObject[k]=subVal;
                                                return ret.promise;
                                        })
                                        );
                                }
                        }
                        else { return [] }

                }
                Q.all(dependents)
                .then(function(){ret.resolve(constructedObject);},ret.reject.bind(ret));

        });
                return ret;
}

getFromRedis( 'greg', function(out) {console.log('Final output: ' + JSON.stringify( out ))} );
```

I can look at the examples and see theoretically how it's supposed to work, but I can't get my mind around how it should work with the q implementation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you previously had a callback-based solution?

Comment: No.  I tried it, but it was way more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try to be as pure as you can when working with promises. Avoid functions that have side effects, i.e. do manipulate any variables outside of their own scope.
- Avoid passing callbacks to functions. Do only pass them to promise methods. You are doing this both with `r_client.smembers()` and when invoking your `getFromRedis` method

I can see only one specific mistake that would keep your script from working:

```
return [];
```

does not have any effect from the callback. So, `ret` is never going to be resolved in this case. You would do `ret.resolve([]); return;` if at all. However, there are better solutions that let you use `return` again.

To restructure your script, there are two points:

- Use the [`Q.nfcall` helper function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfcallfunc-args) (and the like) to avoid dealing with callback-style APIs directly. Use `then` to transform its result then - synchronously returning the tree leaves or a promise for the descendant-getting computations.
- Use [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) first, and then transform its result. Don't add a handler to each `dependent`, but get the whole result and build the `construct` in one single step.

```
function getFromRedis(nodeName){
    return Q.ninvoke(r_client, "smembers", 'parents.' + nodeName).then(function(val) {
        // this is our returned object
        var constructedObject = {label: nodeName};
        if (val) {
            var dependents = val.map(function(par) {
                // get a promise for the next level
                return getFromRedis(nodeName+"."+par.toString());
            });
            return Q.all(dependents).then(function(dependentResults) {
                 constructedObject.parents = dependentResults;
                 return constructedObject;
            });
        } else { 
            return constructedObject; // without parents
        }
    });
}

getFromRedis( 'greg' ).done(function(out) {
    console.log('Final output: ' + JSON.stringify( out ));
});
```

Comment: So much more concise.  It all makes sense when I see it working like this.  For some reason, when I run it from the command line, though, it never returns any output?  It's like it's stuck in a loop.

Comment: Add some logging to see what `val`s you are getting in the while, maybe there really is. I don't know redis well, it's possible that I didn't construct the queries correctly from the values - see the part of the code [which I just edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18905566/revisions), you might need to adapt it.

Comment: Hmm.  Seems like it should work, but I'm getting an error in q.js:

`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sendCommand'
    at exports.commands.forEach.RedisClient.(anonymous function) (/Users/username/node_modules/node-redis/index.js:408:12)
    at Promise.apply (~/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:26)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (~/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at Promise.dispatch (~/node_modules/q/q.js:1337:14)
    at flush (~/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)`

Comment: The one thing that I did change (I get the error either way): smembers gets buffers back from Redis instead of strings.  So I called toString() on 'par'.

Comment: Oh, found [this](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node).  I changed the Q.nfcall() to this: `return Q.ninvoke(r_client, "smembers", 'parents.' + nodeName).then(function(val) {`

I've been banging my head against the wall for the better part of three days trying to figure this out.  Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: Thank you, that makes only sense. Reflected it in my answer :-)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind one more question -- if I wanted to do another redis call (just a 'get' this time), and stick that in the object also, would it be another `Q.ninvoke(r_client, 'get', 'foo.'+nodeName).done()` call?

Comment: Yes. And to merge it with the other result, use `Q.all` again.